# Вычисление кубического корня в sympy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

Код:

```
a = simplify('x**(1/3)')
print(a.subs(x, -10).evalf())
```

Вывод:

```
1.07721734501594 + 1.86579517236206*I
```

Почему он с мнимой единицей? Есть же корень кубический из отрицательного числа? Или я что-то забыл? В чём причина?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта проблема берётся от того, что и стандартно в `python`, если попытаться вычислить выражение `(-10)**(1/3)`, то получим, как раз то, что у вас и получается. (Так как вычисляется 1/3 приближенно, а для числа `0.333333` никакого истинного корня нет. В  [документации](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.5/modules/mpmath/functions/powers.html#cbrt) к cbrt в sympy также явно указано, какой ответ она считает истинным и какой выдаёт, предупреждая что для отрицательных чисел он может отличаться от того, что вы ожидали.

Но вместо возведение в степень `(1/3)` можно использовать функцию [real_root()](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#root) она как раз делает то, что вам нужно:

```
>>> a = simplify('real_root(x, 3)')
... print(a.subs(x, -10).evalf())

−2.15443469003188
```

более того метод [root](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#root) может возвращать и другие корни. В качестве третьего параметра он берёт номер корня, который следует вернуть:

```
>>>root(-10, 3, 0).evalf()
1.07721734501594+1.86579517236206i
>>>root(-10, 3, 1).evalf()
−2.15443469003188
>>>root(-10, 3, 2).evalf()
1.07721734501594−1.86579517236206i
```

Comment: *если попытаться вычислить выражение `(-10)**(1/3)`, то получим, как раз то, что у вас и получается* -- а вы попробуйте.

Comment: `>>>print(((-10)**(1/3)))
(1.0772173450159421+1.865795172362064j)`
python3.5.2 Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А, я понял, это ещё одно отличие между Python 2 и 3. :) Извините за беспокойство.

Comment: Да, в python2 деление с одним слэшом будет целочисленное, а в 3+ уже нет.

Answer (score 3):

### В том, что этих корней среди комплексных чисел *три*.

И это вправду один из них. Полный список:

```
 1.07721734501594 + 1.86579517236206*I # ваш
 1.07721734501594 - 1.86579517236206*I # симметричный относительно оси вещественных
-2.154434690031884                     # то, что вы искали
```

Комплексные корни из вещественных чисел целой степени 3 и более образуют на комплексной плоскости правильный многоугольник, в данном случае это равносторонний треугольник. См. [формулу Муавра](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0).

---

Вам нужно ограничиться вещественными результатами. Чтобы получить все результаты, можно решить уравнение `y = x**(1/3)`, если при этом ещё объявить `y` как вещественное, то комплексные результаты отвалятся.

Но может быть решение и получше, которое я не знаю, т. к. с SymPy не работал.